# Is it possible to loop through a second VBO in the vertex shader?

Tags: opengl, vertex-buffer, vertex-shader

So, let say that I have two vertex buffers. One that describes the actual shape I want to draw, and the other one is able to influence the first one.

So, what I actually want to be able to do is something like this:

```
uniform VBO second_one;

void main()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < size_of_array(second_one); ++i)
    Do things with second_one[i] to alter the values
  create the output informations
}
```

Things I might want to do can be gravity, that that each point in second_one tries to drag a bit the point closer to it and so on and then after the point is adjusted, apply the matrices to have its actual location.

I would be really surprise that it's possible, or something close to it. But the whole point is to be able to use a second VBO, or the make it as a uniform of type vec3 let say so I can access it.

Comment: what's wrong with [arrays](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Types#Arrays)?

Comment: the thing is that I want to use one VBO with the transform feedback because it's very fast. So being able to pass that VBO as a uniform would avoid transfering the same data to the uniform and so on!

Answer (score 1):

For what you're wanting, you have three options.

1. An array of uniforms. GLSL lets you do `uniform vec3 stuff[50];`. And arrays in GLSL have a `.length()` method, so you can find out how big they are. Of course, there are limits to the number of uniforms you use, but you shouldn't need more than 20-30 of these. Anything more than that and you'll really feel the performance drain.
2. [Uniform buffer objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object). These can store a bit more data than non-block uniforms, but they still have limits. And the storage comes from a buffer object. But accesses to them are, depending on hardware, slightly slower than accesses to direct uniforms.
3. [Buffer textures](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Texture). This is a way to attach a buffer object to a texture. With this, you can access vast amounts of memory from within a shader. But be warned: they're *not* fast to access. If you can make due with one of the above methods, do so.

Note that #2 and #3 will only be found on hardware capable of supporting GL 3.x and above. So DX10-class hardware.

Comment: thanks! The reason the first option is the fastest it's because it goes in constant memory. The second one is probably in global memory, so slower, but closer to what I'm trying to do. The last one goes in texture memory!